# Nokogiri results not looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to understand how to scrape pages.

The results are not looping on the view page. It only shows the first one. Why?

LinksController:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

    def craigslist_scrape
        require 'open-uri'

        url = "https://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/web"

        page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

        @craigslist_info = page.css("ul.rows")

        @link_info = @craigslist_info.at_css("li.result-row p.result-info a.result-title.hdrlnk")
        @date = @craigslist_info.at_css("li.result-row p.result-info time.result-date")
    end

end
```

View page: craigslist_scrape.html.erb:

```
<% @craigslist_info.each do |craig| %>
    <p><%= "Title of the job: #{@link_info.text}" %></p>
    <p><%= "Date: #{@date.text}" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Screenshot of only first results:

[image]

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'links#craigslist_scrape'
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170308223314) do
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "links", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "link_info"
    t.string   "date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over `@craigslist_info`, but `.css("ul.rows")` will only pick up a single element. You're also overwriting previous elements each time you call `.at_css`

Try something like:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
@links = page.css("li.result-row p.result-info a.result-title.hdrlnk")
@dates = page.css("li.result-row p.result-info time.result-date")
```

And then in your view:

```
<% @links.each_with_index do |link, index| %>
  <p><%= "Title of the job: #{link.text}" %></p>
  <p><%= "Date: #{@dates[index].text}" %></p>
<% end %>
```

If you want to tidy things up, you can also model the scraped data in an easier to understand form. For example:

```
results = page.css("li.result-row p.result-info")
@result_objects = results.map { |o|
                    OpenStruct.new(
                      link: o.at_css("a.result-title.hdrlnk"),
                      date: o.at_css("time.result-date")
                    )
                  }
```

And then iterate over `@result_objects`, knowing that you can access `.link` and `.date` for each one.

Comment: your answer hit the head of the nail and fixed my problem. thank you. =) may I ask a couple of questions, if you don't mind? why are you doing it with_index, ie, `@links.each_with_index`? and then applying it to `@dates[index]` ... confused about this.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765: no problem :-)  When you use `.css` with nokogiri, it will return a `NodeSet` (http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) which for our purposes, we treat a bit like an array. We can't iterate over two arrays at the same time - but we do know that they contain the same number of items, and are in the same order. Therefore we iterate over `@links`, and then grab the corresponding entry from `@dates`

Comment: And if you're planning to grab lots of values from each result row eventually, it's definitely worth looking at the second option. OpenStruct is really useful here (read more here: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) for grouping together the properties of each result row, and will make your code far more readable. For example, you can iterate like `@result_objects.each { |row| puts row.link; puts row.date }`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you are only scraping the first page of results. If you go to the url you are scraping "https://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/web" you can see that it's only showing you the first 100 results. If you scroll down and click "next" the link changes to "https://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/web?s=100". If you want to scrape ALL results, you need to create a method to scrape each page of the results.

Comment: thanks for looking at my question! Actually, I'm not looking to scrape ALL the results but just the first page. I'm only literally getting the first one on the first page. Hence why I'm puzzled that my looping is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Within your iteration of @craigslist_info, you are not referencing the placeholder, craig, and instead referencing only @link_info and @date. This will only produce one result. Within your iteration, you want to access the link_info and date of "craig".

```
<% @craigslist_info.each do |craig| %>
    <% link_info = craig.at_css("li.result-row p.result-info a.result-title.hdrlnk") %> 
    <% date = craig.at_css("li.result-row p.result-info time.result-date")%>
    <p><%= "Title of the job: #{link_info.text}" %></p>
    <p><%= "Date: #{date.text}" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: your answer makes sense, and I copied your loop ... but it's still showing only one result .. the same one as in the screenshot above .. and everything else is still intact as in the post ... is there something else I'm missing?